# How do I figure out if my wireless network has WEP, WPA or WPA2 security via command prompt on Windows XP?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, security, network-protocols

I understand how to check what security protocol my wireless network connection is currently using by going to the Wireless Network Connection window like in the following example

[image]

but **how does one check what wireless security protocol one's wireless network is currently using from command prompt?**

NOTE:

*The reason I ask is because my Ubuntu laptop's network connection is currently set to WPA & WPA2 Personal but when ever it connects it auto switches to WEP which is a major concern. So I need to make sure if it's an OS issue with Ubuntu or if it's a router issue.*

*The only way to do that is to find out beyond a shadow of a doubt which security is protocol Windows XP is using  currently. While my Windows XP Wireless Network Connection window tells me I am connected via WPA, I need to see the command line result to be certain. I don't trust the GUI.*

Comment: You could also use one of the myriad third-party WiFi network discovery tools to check the encryption type. Xirrus Wi-Fi Inspector should do the trick. Getting this via native command-line options in Windows XP is probably not possible. Even with PowerShell installed, there's not likely to be an XP-available cmdlet (Windows 8 maybe, XP/7 no). You *might* be able to get something with `wmic` or `Get-WmiObject`, but I'm not certain how or even if that's possible on XP/7.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, once doesn't exist natively in Windows and I do not know of any third party tools that do so.

While the "netsh" utility did exist in XP, Windows did not have the "wlan" functionality added to it until Windows Vista.

On Win7 or later, from the command prompt, enter "netsh wlan show interfaces" and you will get what you want.  This may work on Vista as well, however I haven't been on a Vista machine in a long time and as I recall it doesn't have the more complete "wlan" functionality of later releases so I am unsure if this was included in the functionality.